# create an SQL schema from a select statement

Tags: t-sql

I was doing the boring work of writing out a schema for a t-sql table that I will populate from a stored procedure and realized that it should be entirely possible to do most of the work of creating schema by having a query that concatenates the names of the fields in a query with the data types. I'm sure I can figure it out, but figured I'd ask here since I expect someone has already done it for me.

Comment: *"concatenates the names of the fields in a query with the data types."* <-- What "query"? I assume you have metadata about the table(s) needing to be created tucked away somewhere? Can you explain more about what have to work with and what your expected output is? Right now this question is very answerable as there is no one-size fits all solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write SQL similar to this:

SELECT col1, col2, col3 INTO newTable FROM table1;